# Prevent container from exiting, conditionally

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I have this entrypoint in a Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["r2g", "run"]
```

and I run the resulting image with:

```
docker run --name "$container" "$tag"
```

most of the time, I want the container to exit when it's done - the r2g process is not a server, but a testing command line tool. **So my question is** - if I want to conditionally keep the container from exiting, is there a flag I can pass to `docker run` to keep the container alive? Can I add something to ENTRYPOINT to keep the container alive?

Comment: Container is nothing magical. It's just a process, like any other program. Ask yourself a question what would you do to prevent a process (your entrypoint) from terminating?

Comment: pass a flag to the `docker run` executable to tell it to not exit?

Comment: This does not make any sense and is not possible. You can't tell a process to "not terminate". If it terminates it terminates. All Docker can do is to restart it. This is what `--restart-policy` is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to keep the docker container running is making it run a command that does not exit.

In your case, when you don't want the container to exit, you could run something like this:

```
docker run --name "$container" "$tag" sh -c "r2g run && sleep infinity"
```

This way, once the `r2g` command is finished, your container will wait indefinitely and keep running.

Comment: that should work, although I would be surprised if there is no argument to `docker run` that can keep it alive, something like `docker run --wait` or `docker run --forever` or whatever

Comment: No there is not. As emix said in a comment, docker is Simply a wrapper around an executable. There's no way to keep an executable running forever doing nothing if it is not designed to do that.